# sql select statement to display distinct combination of two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sql `Table` `Messages`
it has **4 columns** which are

```
1. sno 
2. sender_id 
3. reciever_id 
4. message
```

i hv to make a `SELECT` statement which is a `unique combination` of **sender_id** and **reciever_id** when either of them is equal to 1.

Also i want that if a combination of **(1,3)** is included , the **(3,1)** should be ignored

help will be appreciated

Comment: Ya great, so did you tried anything yourself first?

Comment: Yes, i tried to select distinct sender_id , reciever_id

also, tried group by clause but it returns both (1,3)(3,1)

Comment: @LokeshDevnani include then your query that you come up with so far in your post so that the likelihood of being help with your problem would be higher than nothing at all.

Comment: Ok, edper..thnx for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL that works in most RDBMS:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN sender_id > reciever_id THEN reciever_id ELSE sender_id END,
    CASE WHEN sender_id > reciever_id THEN sender_id ELSE reciever_id END
FROM
    MyTable;
```

MySQL SQL dialect (and ANSI SQL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    LEAST(sender_id, reciever_id)
    GREATEST(sender_id, reciever_id)
FROM
    MyTable;
```

Edit, after @Edper's comment

The CASE condition changes, but the THEN/ELSE columns need swapped too

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN sender_id > reciever_id THEN reciever_id ELSE sender_id END,
    CASE WHEN sender_id <= reciever_id THEN reciever_id ELSE sender_id END
FROM
    MyTable;
```

Comment: +1 simple and elegant :)

Comment: @gbn for the Standard SQL the > operator on the 2nd CASE WHEN, should it not be < operator instead?

Comment: @Edper: in this case no, because the THEN/ELSE columns are swapped. Updated to show this

Comment: Excellent approach man by the use of least and greatest..you made this very simple. This trick didn't hit my mind before.

Comment: `greatest()` and `least()` *are* defined in the SQL standard so the second query is "standard SQL" as well

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: true. I should have said "works in most RDBMS". SQL Server does not have them for example

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.sender_id ,
    a.reciever_id
FROM
    Messages a
LEFT JOIN Messages b 
    ON a.sender_id = b.reciever_id
    AND b.sender_id = a.reciever_id
WHERE
    b.sender_id IS NULL
GROUP BY
    a.sender_id ,
    a.reciever_id
ORDER BY 
    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

create table #temp(sno int , sender_id  int, reciever_id int)

insert into #temp

select '1','1','1'

union all

select '2','2','2'

union all

select '3','3','3'

union all

select '1','1','1'

union all

select '2','2','2'

union all

select '3','3','3'

union  all

select '3','3','3'

union  all

select '1','1','3'

union  all

select '1','3','1'

union  all

select '1','4','1'

union  all

select '1','1','4'

----TRY THIS:-

;

With T( sender_id, reciever_id,dis )

AS

(
select sender_id, reciever_id ,ROW_NUMBER() over(PARTITION BY (sender_id+reciever_id ) order by (sender_id+reciever_id ))  as dis from #temp

where (sender_id=1 or reciever_id=1)

group by sender_id, reciever_id

)

SELECT  sender_id, reciever_id FROM T

where dis=1